# Adding items from custom variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd defined this interface:

```
interface ICommand {
   regexp: RegExp;
   callback: Function;
}

interface ICommandList {
   [Phrae: string] : ICommand; 
}
```

and defined a variable as this:

```
namespace CORE{

export let commands: ICommandList;

// (?: | ) non counting group, not to be consider in params
// ( | )? existing or non existing it is the sam impact (one or zero) (? after the reg)
commands = {
   'test': {
         regexp: /^What is your (?:first|family) name (man|guy)$/,   
         callback: (...parameters:string[])=>alert('my name is: '+parameters[1]) //itemsIdentification,
   },

   'items identification': {
         regexp: /^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me)?\s?(the)?\s?meaning of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/,
         callback: (x:string)=>alert('hi 1'+x) //itemsIdentification,
   },

   'ML SoH': {
         regexp: /^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me) the (stock|inventory) of ML$/,
         callback: ()=>alert('hi 2') //mlSOH,
   },

    'Report stock on hand': {
         regexp: /^(What is|What's) (our|the) (stock|inventory|SoH) of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/,
         callback: ()=>alert('hi 3') //SoH,
        },

     'Basic Mathematical Opertions': {
               // ?\s? can be used instead of space, also could use /i instead of $/,
                regexp: /^(What is|What's|Calculate|How much is) ([\w.]+) (\+|and|plus|\-|less|minus|\*|\x|by|multiplied by|\/|over|divided by) ([\w.]+)$/,
                callback: ()=>alert('hi 4') //math,
              },
  };
}
```

I wanted to `ADD` more items for this variable `in other files`, so I wrote another file with this:

```
namespace CORE{
    commands += {
        'test2': {
         regexp: /^What is your (?:first|family) name (man|guy)$/,   
         callback: (...parameters:string[])=>alert('my name is: '+parameters[1]) //itemsIdentification,
   }
    };

}
```

but it gave me error as seen below, my question is:
How can I add more items for this variable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property assignment:

```
commands["test2"] = {
    regexp: /^What is your (?:first|family) name (man|guy)$/,
    callback: (...parameters: string[]) => alert('my name is: ' + parameters[1]) //itemsIdentification,
};
```

Comment: Thank, it worked.
I'll wait little bit before accepting your answer, may get some other answer that enable me adding lots of lines in a simpler way.